# Delete OpenCV 3.1 completly

Tags: opencv

I installed the OpenCv 3.1 months ago and it caused problem because of my assignment need a lower version of openCv now i searched on web and find some uninstall function. Seems work to me but when i tried to install OpenCv using this code:

```
sudo apt-get install libdevil-dev libboost-dev cmake cmake-qt-gui gcc- 4.8 g++-4.8 libgtk2.0-dev libeigen3-dev mesa-common-dev libopencv-dev
```

it gives me that my version is already uptodate. Can someone help me?

```
dev cmake cmake-qt-gui gcc-4.8
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
»libboost-dev« ist bereits die neuste Version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1).
»gcc-4.8« ist bereits die neuste Version (4.8.5-4ubuntu2).
»libdevil-dev« ist bereits die neuste Version (1.7.8-10).
»cmake« ist bereits die neuste Version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3).
»cmake-qt-gui« ist bereits die neuste Version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 13 nicht aktualisiert.
```

Comment: It looks like you only executed half of the command - the message is just telling you that your system already has the development packages (not surprisingly - since you previously installed a newer version of OpenCV, presumably from source)

Comment: what kind of command should i use there and to delete everything and install the old version?

Comment: Do you really have a space between `gcc-` and `4.8`?, cause this will try to remove gcc and install 4.8, which is probably what not you want.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer below, I make the presumption that you installed version 3.1 from the source or possibly from a PPA. Also note that I have not configured OpenCV to work with Python on my installation.

### Removing Old Installation

**Method 1**

If you compiled OpenCV version 3.1 via CMake, you should still have the directory you compiled the source in (i.e. your build directory). Navigate to it. Once there you can type `make uninstall` to remove all files moved during the install process.

**Warning:** I've read that this can cause issues but have not personally witnessed any.

**Note:** This method leaves empty directories behind. They do not cause any issues, but if you would like to remove them manually, you can.

**Method 2 (more dangerous!)**

You can use the command `sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;` to locate all files with the word opencv in their name and remove. As is, this command will present a prompt for you to confirm whether or not you want to delete each individual file found. This will take a long time. **Caution:** Take care when deleting files. Always check the location of the file and ensure that it can safely be deleted before proceeding.

### Installing an Older Version of OpenCV

**Note:** I use gcc and g++ mostly and do not use an IDE. If you would like to use an IDE, additional or different steps may be necessary.

Generally, I find the best way to set up OpenCV (and other libraries that I build from source) is to create a folder in my HOME directory called separate-libs (you can name yours whatever you want). Then inside I create a directory for the library itself, extract the source code and compile it with a custom install prefix. When compiling OpenCV with CMake, this is straightforward.
Here's how I did it on my machine:

- Install all necessary dependencies. This can be tricky, but there are many online guides that detail all of the dependencies needed to compile OpenCV from source.

  - Typically, each release of OpenCV contains a list of required and optional dependencies in the release's documentation. You can locate it for any particular release by going [here](https://opencv.org/releases.html) and clicking Documentation > OpenCV Tutorials > Introduction to OpenCV > Installation in Linux.
  - There may be optional dependencies that are specific to your needs. It is up to you to find those dependencies. If you don't know what build options there are for OpenCV look under "OpenCV cmake options" in the [CmakeLists.txt](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) file included with the source code.

After setting up your dependencies, you can build using either the CMake GUI or terminal.
**For GUI**

- Open and select browse source: then select the folder containing the uncompressed source code.
- Select browse build: then select the desired build directory
- Click Add Entry: then click on the dropdown that says BOOL and select PATH. In the name textfield type CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. Then provide an installation path.
- Click Generate to see available configuration options. Those that have a path at the end means that OpenCV successfully located the library. If not you will either have to install or manually point to the library (if in a non-standard location).
- Once everything is correctly configured, click generate to create a makefile with those configurations set.
- Next type `make -j$(nproc)`. This will compile the code.

  - The -j option for make splits the job into multiple processes.
  - $(nproc) feeds -j the number of processors you have, which will allow for multitasking and quicker compilation.
  - For reference, on a laptop with an i7 and 8GB of RAM, compiling OpenCV with the extra-contrib-modules took roughly 20-30 minutes.
- Once the compilation finishes type `make install` to move all files to the install directory.

**From Terminal**

- Navigate to your build directory (create one with mkdir if you do not have one) and type `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=absolute_path_to_installation_directory -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"`. Add additional -D*build_flag*=*option* to suit your needs. **Note:** do not put a space after or before the equal sign.
- Once the command is configured with all the options you want, press enter. This shouldn't take too long.

  - You might see a few errors. Most of them are not severe and will not cause problems.
  - If you forgot an build option, cmake command just used and enter the flag you forgot and press enter to regenerate the makefile.
- Next type `make -j$(nproc)`. This is the same as if installing from the GUI.
- Once the compilation finishes type `make install`.

Once completed, I use aliases and pkg-config to make compilation easier. In the installation directory in `/lib/pkgconfig/` there is a single file called opencv.pc. This is a file that pkg-config can use to automatically configure the library on a need basis. The less secure option is to copy or move this .pc file to a directory where pkg-config looks by default. Since these are system folders, placing files from outside repositories in them is usually advised against. Instead, I open my ~/.bashrc file and at the bottom place the lines 
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$opencv2prefix/lib/pkgconfig"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$opencv2prefix/lib"
 alias opencv2="pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv2"`.

In the lines above, $opencv2prefix is a variable containing the path to the folder I installed OpenCV in. Instead of the alias command using opencv2, yours will likely be opencv. The opencv2 after `--libs` refers to the name of the .pc file. This may be different in your case. I changed mine because I have two versions of OpenCV on my machine.

Now, when I go to compile with gcc or g++, I simply type `g++ main.cpp $(opencv2)`. Substitute what's in $() with the name of the alias that performs pkg-config.